# Is it possible from the event interface, to check if the event.target has property checked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a list of checkbox elements on the DOM. When a checkbox is selected, I have a onChange function that is passed the event. Is there a way to check if the event.target has property of checked?

I've tried things like event.target.style, but I know that this would not follow the same pattern.

```
let option = <input onChange={(event)=>{this.onchange(event)}} type='checkbox' checked/>

onchange = (event) => {
  //Can i verify if event.target has checked attribute or not?
}
```

Comment: if (!chkbx.checked) { ...

Comment: @ControlAltDel oh I see that the event.target has checked property

Comment: so i could just do something like:
```if (event.target.checked){
}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [here in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

> ```
> ...
> const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
> ...
> ```

You do a `if` with `event.target.checked`

```
let option = <input onChange={(event)=>{this.onchange(event)}} type='checkbox' checked/>

onchange = (event) => {
    if(event.target.checked){
        // do what you want to do when the input have `checked`
    }
}
```